# Как записать из javascript в post

Tags: javascript

Как можно записать данные javascriptom в post запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с jquery:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
```

Если без - [xmlhttprequest](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/)

Comment: @bo6ji9 сейчас так не работает
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.SendOrder.host2.value = zeroes;
    </script>

Comment: так не работает в чем может быть дело

Comment: @eldqs, смотри в консоль

Comment: @stck я не знаю о какой консоли вы говорите, ведь по идее этот скрипт должен работать, но он не работает, почему

Comment: @eldqs, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp    SendOrder вообще не существует... выложите на jsfiddle более подробный код, не понятно, что конкретно вы хотите сделать, в таком случае

Comment: > я не знаю о какой консоли вы говорите

@eldqs, консоль браузера. `Ctrl+Shift+J` в Chrome и Firefox, `F12` в Internet Explorer.